# 9v to 12v using buck booster

Tags: batteries, voltage-regulator, amperage

I'm a computer science student with very very less electrical knowledge, I need to boost 12v with 1-2A from a 9v box type battery, on searching I found XL6009 buck booster can step up voltage, can I get enough Amps on using it?

Comment: There's thousands of boost converters that can do that. Go to the website of any major semiconductor manufacturer, e.g. ti.com, and use the power supply designer there to design a circuit that does what you need.

Comment: 1) You should try to be more accurate with your nomenclature: a boost converter increases the voltage, a buck converter decreases the voltage, and a buck-boost convertor (which is what an XL6009 is, when using appropriate ancillary components) is capable of both. 2) Power out = (power in * efficiency); power = volts * current. Assuming 85% efficiency, to get 2 A at 12 V it needs 2 A * 12 V / 9 V * 0.85 = 2.3 A from the battery. Can the battery supply that continuously?

Comment: 3) A datasheet (always check the datasheet) for a [module using an XL6009](http://www.instructables.com/id/The-Introduction-of-XL6009-Step-up-Power-Module-DC/) states a maximum of 4 A *input* current, so you are OK there with *that* module. Other modules may have different specifications.

Comment: it can provide upto 300 ma only

Comment: is there any other type of battery so that I can use them? (like multiple AA batteries)

Comment: @Dharanendiran Are there any fixed constraints on the battery size, and do you want to use rechargeable cells? How long do you want the battery to last in use?

Comment: @AndrewMorton Small size batteries are preferable, It's enough to last for 7-8 hours

Comment: @Dharanendiran You need to investigate how to choose the correct battery capacity for your use. There is a small summary at [How To Choose Battery](http://www.batteryspace.com/howtochoosebattery.aspx). Note that a higher battery voltage will result in a lower current draw from the battery. Running your circuit from a mains adapter may be a better idea than a ~225 Wh battery.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*I need to boost 12v with 1-2A from a 9v box type battery, on searching I found XL6009 buck booster can step up voltage, can I get enough Amps on using it?*

No you can't. The problem is not the XL6009 because it can supply up to about 4 A. The problem is the 9 V battery. I''m assuming you intend to use a 9 V PP3 size like this one:
[image]

This type of battery cannot supply enough power. You need about 12 V 1 to 2 A which means 12 W to 24 W. This type of battery is intended for applications up to like 1 or 2 W maybe.

So you need to choose a different type of battery, for example 8 AA cells in series and even that would be pushing the limits.

If you need to increase the voltage then instead of looking to build something using an IC like the XL6009 I strongly recommend to use a ready-made module. You can find these on ebay, for example: [this one](http://www.ebay.com/itm/NEW-XL6009-DC-Adjustable-Step-up-boost-Power-Converter-Module-Replace-LM2577-/252769759576?hash=item3ada407158:g:vOQAAOSw9IpXyany).

[image]

Building a PCB with a switched converter and all the right components without experience is a recipe for problems if you ask me. You need some experience to do this properly. Modules like the one suggested are cheap and easy to use, giving a much better chance of success.